# Ruby "end" statement problems

Tags: ruby

I am stuck with a program that won't run properly. Here is my code:

```
puts '<Input greeting below>'
answer = gets.chomp
if answer == 'Hello' || 'Hi'
  answer == true
else 
  answer == false
  puts 'Hey, how are you?'
  answer2 = gets.chomp
  if answer2 == 'I\'m good' || 'I\'m doing well'
    answer2 == true
  else 
    answer2 == false
    puts 'That\'s good. Would you like to know facts about ruby programming?'
    answer3 = gets.chomp
    if answer3 == 'Sure'
      answer3 == true
    else 
      answer3 == false
      puts 'Ok, well did you know that {hello, world} was the first program ever made?'
      answer4 = gets.chomp
      if answer4 == 'Yes'
        answer4 == true
      else 
        answer4 == false
        puts 'Wow, you\'re pretty good! Would you like to know another fact?'
        answer5 = gets.chomp
        if answer5 == 'Sure'
          answer5 == true
        else answer5 == false
          puts 'Alright, did you know the programming language "Ruby" 
          was developed by a Japanese techonolgist named "Yukihiro Matsumoto"
          because he wasn\'t satisfied with the other programming languages?'
        end 
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

Windows CMD says that I have a problem on line 29 with the "end" part. I can't figure it out. Can someone please help?

Comment: What you're doing here is a massive anti-pattern. Using a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) would make this significantly more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, `answer == 'Hello' || 'Hi'` won't give you the result you think it will give you. It will actually always return `true`. You are thinking of `answer == 'Hello' || answer == 'Hi'` or even better, `%w{Hello Hi}.include? answer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a number of problems here that need to be fixed before you can get a working program.

First up, `if x == A || B` does not mean what you think it does. This evaluates to `if x == (A || B)` where it will only compare to the first string, not the second. To test against multiple possible matches the best approach is to use `case`:

```
case (answer)
when 'Hello', 'Hi'
  # Matches!
else
  # Not matched
end
```

You can also break out several different conditions by adding additional `when` clauses, and you can even use regular expressions to catch variations in case, and so forth.

As I added in a comment, this nested `if` pattern needs to go away. You need to switch to a state system instead:

```
state = :greeting

loop do
  case (state)
  when :greeting
    puts "<input greeting below>"
    case (gets.chomp)
    when "Hello", "Hi"
      state = :how_are_you
    else
      break
    end
  when :how_are_you
    puts "Hey, how are you?"
    case (gets.chomp)
    when "I'm good", "I'm doing well"
      state = :thats_good
    else
      break
    end
  # ... Additional `when` clauses.
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @tadman I fixed my program with your help, but one thing though, I'm not an experienced programmer so I have no idea what you typed in your second example, nonetheless, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @GurvSwerve When confronted with code you don't understand, study it: work it through, line by line if necessary, use puts, pry, a debugger, etc to work it out.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for your advice, I'll take it into consideration next time I ask a question, cheers! :)